# SQL Server convert into number without 'oz'

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server, I have a column (`dimension_value`) that contains a number and an 'oz' at the end in the format of `number-oz`. I have a table A and a table B and I want to see if the "number-oz" in table A is less than than the "number-oz" in table B to compare the prices.

For example (some of results)

```
(TABLE A) 17 oz 43.99       
(TABLE B) 6.7 oz    25.99

(TABLE A) 10 oz 48.99   
(TABLE B) 3.38 oz   31.99

(TABLE A) 10.1 oz   26.99   
(TABLE B) 3.4 oz    20.99
```

I was trying to do in my `SELECT` statement:

```
CONVERT(SUBSTRING(pom.dimension_value, 'oz', -3), UNSIGNED INTEGER) AS num
```

But it gives me an error...

> Incorrect syntax near ','

Comment: Please see the documentation for [`SUBSTRING`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx) and [`CONVERT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

Comment: Terrible database design leads to problems like this...

Comment: `CHARINDEX` and `REPLACE` might help as well.

Comment: The error message is pretty terse, but it is probably complaining that the second argument to `SUBSTRING` is not an integer.  You will need to nest another function in the expression to identify where "oz" starts in the string.

Comment: Is there a version of sql-server that has "unsigned integer" as a datatype now?

Comment: There is not unsigned int type in any version of SQL Server. Don't bother looking for it.

Answer (score 1):

As Rick S pointed out, this is a bad design for your database.
It's never a good idea to keep both values and units in the same column.
If possible, change the database design.
If not, use `REPLACE` to remove the `'oz'` part and cast to int (There is no such thing as unsigned integer in SQL Server).

```
CAST(REPLACE(pom.dimension_value, ' oz', '') AS Int)
```